# Entity framework exception" the specified type member not supported in linq to entities, only properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, ef-code-first

The following code snapet throw an exception.

```
 public Models.Web.User GetLogingUser(string username, string password)
   {
       using (Data.User_Repository repository = new Data.User_Repository())
       {
      IQueryable<Models.Web.User> query = repository.FindAll().Select(x =>new             Models.Web.User()).Where(c => c.UserName.Equals(username.ToString())).AsQueryable();
           return query.Where(x => x.Password.Equals(password.ToString())).First();
       }
   }
```

here the repositry class has the generic method insert, update, delete , find , findall etc.
during debugging I found that for the entered user name record are retrieved but when it assign to "query" variable i get the following error exception. kindly help me. thanks
"
The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: password and username are already strings, where are you calling .ToString()?

Comment: what is the type of c.UserName ?

Comment: you are right. both are string type, there is no need .ToString(). but the actual issues are not related to .ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Its the .Equals() that is your issue.  Use `==,` since this is going to be executed on the database server, it will use the case comparison type which is configured for your database.

Comment: Also try it without the .ToString()

Comment: public class User{public string UserName{get; set;} public string Password{get; set;}}

Comment: NOte : the properties name are same as in DB.